# What do we need to do to get a cool looking banner?

Tags: discussion

From my understanding, Fitness.SE recently left BETA status. The rest of the stacks that are not in BETA usually have some cool looking banners (as well as symbols in the network questions list). Though, not all. So there must be some distinction.

[image: Puzzling Banner]

[image: Arqade Banner]

[image: Sci-fi & Fantasy Banner]

[image: Fitness Banner]

What kind of accolades do we need to achieve in order to get a sweet looking banner for little-ole Fitness.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to fully graduate, unfortunately, which means (mainly) that our questions per day need to jump drastically. 10 QPD (ish) is the benchmark for a full graduation, with new site design, new reputation levels, etc.

What our graduation means is that we are no longer listed as "beta" but moved to launched, the word beta goes away from the title, reputation requirements remain at beta levels (Such as 4k for moderator tools as opposed to 20k on a fully graduated site, 5k vs 25k for site analytics tools, etc) , and (eventually) there will be site moderator elections as opposed to appointed moderators.

Comment: Do you know what the current QPD is?

Comment: @C.Lange - All site statistics (all sites) are always available on Area 51. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7080/physical-fitness - We are at 2.1 QPD. Far behind some sites, not really that far from others.